# Fetching number of tickets per order

Tags: eventbrite

AFAIK the Eventbrite API does not return the number of tickets per order. Is there some way to find that info?

Comment: Yes, several times, but no reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question and say No, fetching the number of tickets per order is not possible. I've asked it directly to the Eventbrite support and API teams without any response and no one here has been able to provide any way to do so either.